# Packed Excel Addin not working created using Excel DNA c#

Tags: c#, excel, excel-dna

I have an AddIn created using Excel DNA c#.
Everything  works fine. 
I've packed the  required dll's in .dna file my dna file is as follows

```
 <DnaLibrary RuntimeVersion="v4.0" Language="C#">    
  <ExternalLibrary Path="ExcelAddInClient.dll" Pack="true"/>
  <ExternalLibrary Path="Newtonsoft.Json.dll" Pack="true"/>
  <ExternalLibrary Path="System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll" Pack="true"/>
  <ExternalLibrary Path="AuthenticationDll.dll" Pack="true"/>
 </DnaLibrary>
```

when i double click the packed filed from Release folder it works fine.but if i copy that xll file to some other location its not working.It doesn't show any Error but It doesn't shows the Desired Output as well.
I am not geting why???

Answer (score 5):

Only the Excel add-in assembly should be referenced using the `ExternalLibrary` tag in the .dna file.

All other assemblies should be using `Reference`.

E.g.

```
<DnaLibrary RuntimeVersion="v4.0" Language="C#">    
  <ExternalLibrary Path="ExcelAddInClient.dll" Pack="true"/>
  <Reference Path="Newtonsoft.Json.dll" Pack="true"/>
  <Reference Path="System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll" Pack="true"/>
  <Reference Path="AuthenticationDll.dll" Pack="true"/>
</DnaLibrary>
```

Answer (score 3):

You are probably missing some dlls, or other necessary files.  Look in the release folder, and see what else is there.

You could try copying all of the other files along with the packed xll, and then deleting these other files one at a time to see which ones are necessary.  Then add these extra necessary files into the dna file.

Also, did you know that you can debug into Excel?  Use "Debug"/"Attach to Process", from Visual Studio, and connect to Excel.  Then open the xll from Excel.  This will hopefully show you the error.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I worked out the issue by looking at the output of the compile step.

`View..Output` should have no obvious errors. This is what it should look like:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: ExcelDNA2, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
1>  ExcelDNA2 -> H:\Test\Docs\SpecsProofOfConcept\ExcelDNA2\bin\Release\ExcelDNA2.dll
1>  H:\Test\Docs\SpecsProofOfConcept\\packages\ExcelDna.AddIn.0.33.9\tools\ExcelDna.xll
1>  1 File(s) copied
1>  H:\Test\Docs\SpecsProofOfConcept\ExcelDNA2\bin\Release\ExcelDNA2-AddIn.dna
1>  1 File(s) copied
1>  H:\Test\Docs\SpecsProofOfConcept\\packages\ExcelDna.AddIn.0.33.9\tools\ExcelDna64.xll
1>  1 File(s) copied
1>  Using base add-in H:\Test\Docs\SpecsProofOfConcept\ExcelDNA2\bin\Release\ExcelDNA2-AddIn.xll
1>    ->  Updating resource: Type: ASSEMBLY_LZMA, Name: EXCELDNA.INTEGRATION, Length: 63672
1>    ~~> ExternalLibrary path ExcelDNA2.dll resolved to H:\Test\Docs\SpecsProofOfConcept\ExcelDNA2\bin\Release\ExcelDNA2.dll.
1>    ->  Updating resource: Type: ASSEMBLY_LZMA, Name: EXCELDNA2, Length: 1605
1>    ->  Updating resource: Type: DNA, Name: __MAIN__, Length: 417
1>  Completed Packing H:\Test\Docs\SpecsProofOfConcept\ExcelDNA2\bin\Release\ExcelDNA2-AddIn-packed.xll.
1>  Using base add-in H:\Test\Docs\SpecsProofOfConcept\ExcelDNA2\bin\Release\ExcelDNA2-AddIn64.xll
1>    ->  Updating resource: Type: ASSEMBLY_LZMA, Name: EXCELDNA.INTEGRATION, Length: 63672
1>    ~~> ExternalLibrary path ExcelDNA2.dll resolved to H:\Test\Docs\SpecsProofOfConcept\ExcelDNA2\bin\Release\ExcelDNA2.dll.
1>    ->  Updating resource: Type: ASSEMBLY_LZMA, Name: EXCELDNA2, Length: 1605
1>    ->  Updating resource: Type: DNA, Name: __MAIN__, Length: 417
1>  Completed Packing H:\Test\Docs\SpecsProofOfConcept\ExcelDNA2\bin\Release\ExcelDNA2-AddIn64-packed.xll.
1>  H:\Test\Docs\SpecsProofOfConcept\ExcelDNA2\bin\Release\ExcelDNA2-AddIn64.dna
1>  1 File(s) copied
1>  H:\Test\Docs\SpecsProofOfConcept\ExcelDNA2\bin\Release\ExcelDNA2-AddIn64.xll
1>  1 File(s) copied
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 15 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

In my case, it was printing many `null reference` exceptions in the build output.

It turned out that I had created a `console` application rather than a `class library`, and when the NuGet package was added, it created the `.dna` file pointing to `ExcelDNSA2.exe`, rather than `ExcelDNSA2.dll`.

Fix this, and everything worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Mark, you are probably missing some of your dlls, or they aren't being included in the packing.
I've found that you really need to pay attention to the output of the build commands if things aren't working as expected.

The dlls will need to either exist, and be registered on the deployment machine, or will need to be included in your Visual Studio output directory so that the packing includes them.  If they can't be found it doesn't flag any error to Visual Studio, it just tells such in the output window.